# Attachment not working with intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have tried two ways to get attachment to SMS one hardcoded (the file 100% exists) I have checked many times.:

```
Intent sms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,
                Uri.parse("smsto:" + number));
        sms.putExtra("sms_body", smsBody);
        sms.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, "file:///storage/sdcard/Pictures/ImageApp/IMG_20160107_133123.jpg");
        startActivity(sms);
```

The other:

```
        Uri picture = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);

        String smsBody = "This is an SMS!";

        Intent sms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,
                Uri.parse("smsto:" + number));
        sms.putExtra("sms_body", smsBody);
        sms.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pictureFile);
        startActivity(sms);
```

The picture variable in debug returns something like:

```
   file:///storage/sdcard/Pictures/ImageApp/IMG_20160107_144801.jpg
```

This also exists, I've checked the ADM.

What is the problem? Why is the picture not being transferred to the attachment? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding the type

```
sms.setType("application/image");
```

or

```
sms.setType("image/jpeg");
```

this should work

Comment: I've tried:
         String smsBody = "This is an SMS!";

        Intent sms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,
                Uri.parse("smsto:" + number));
        sms.putExtra("sms_body", smsBody);
        sms.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
        sms.setType("image/jpeg");
         and I'm getting android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO typ=image/jpeg (has extras) }

Comment: although I have available Google Messaging app available